# The easiest way to represent (complex) tables generate their code latex ( a group of tables) which have not same repartition on latex by excel

Tags: tables, excel

(An urgent appel for experts in tables on latex) 
I have different tables which have not same number of columns (differents repartition columns, lines etc etc (please see the

[image: table]

figure) I am obliged to make all of them as one table as showed here: [link table](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOZ1c1THNkY21iUkE?usp=sharing) my first question:
  is there anyway to make such table I have heard about excel ( generate the latex code of a table after just writing a funtion, I think this could save time and make it easy for begginners( just like me).. anyone has any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build such a tabular with Excel, go ahead, produce a PDF or a picture of it and include it into you file with the graphicx package.

With LaTeX it is tricky. You didn't provide anything than this picture. I thought about a solution, but this is the only more or less working idea. I'm sure it can be done better.

```
\documentclass[pagesize, english, fontsize=10pt, DIV=25]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, lmodern, array, booktabs, ragged2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|*{10}{p{1.3cm}|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}}\toprule
  \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\textbf{Genetic Algorithms (GA)}}\\\midrule
  Data set & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Conventional} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{OIGA} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{dunnemols}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Wohinauimmer}} & Last
  \\\midrule
  \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\dots}\\
  Wine & 83 & 356 & 82 & 786 & 92 & 478 & 82 & 716 & 86\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
  \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\textbf{Decision Tree}}\\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
\end{tabular*}\\%  
\indent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\Centering}p{5.73cm}}|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
    Data set & ITI & i+Learning \\\midrule\addlinespace[1ex]
         Cleve & 65 & 81 \\
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dots}\\
  \end{tabular*}%
\end{document}
```

The `tabular*` environment makes tabulars with a certain width. The trick is to set the width of the different tabulars in correspondence. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration, am really gratefull for you, just I have  a problem if I would put it in pdf and include it it would not been added on my list of tables automatically! how can I do it manually( maybee you would need more information am using this template( I have to use it :|) how to add a title of my pdf( which is a table) after including it to in this template  ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOUVB5amhseWcxUlk/view?usp=sharing) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOQUp3M3dmS04wNzQ/view?usp=sharing here is my doc :)

Comment: So your real issue is, how to get a existing picture / PDF into your list of tables? That is something completely different than your question above, isn't it!  So please ask a new question: How to include a PDF in a document and getting an entry of it into the list of tables. While we are at it: You need to provide a minimal working example. Probably you can include the pdf with the mentioned graphicx package or with the pdfpages packes. There is a feature `\pagecommand`. Get the manual with `texdoc pdfpages`, like usually!

Comment: by the way can you please gives me the instruction, particularly how to manipulate it so that it would be in the middle as you can see there is a margin I have to respect it, and how to add manually (if we could  be done automatically  it would be great) because I have to put a caption after the whole table (you see the document, it maybe be splited on several page ( see here and do like it is an only table and add a caption for it.. here is my table https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOemgtcEJvUjBzcWM?usp=sharing

Comment: basically I have to do it on latex but since it seems to be a bit triky and am new on latex I avoid it :|

Comment: okey thank you any way :) am really gratefull for you

Comment: Sorry, I won't load down and install an unkown documentclass and start experimenting with it. Really, make an MWE and ask a short new question. `texdoc packagename` on the command line is your friend!